# CDP container in Active Directory required if not part of AD?

Tags: ad-certificate-services, pki

We have a Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services **Enterprise CA**.

After installing the service, an AD container is created within `CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com`

Our CDP is http-only. There is no LDAP path added. Should I keep or remove this container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it as is. Just do not use (as you already do) and keep it empty.

Comment: Alright. Wasn't sure if the AD computers query it, while the ADCS server perhaps never updates it.

Comment: If there are no references to CDP container in certificates, no one will query it.